# Alpine.js - How do I listen to events dispatched by other libraries?

Tags: bootstrap-select, alpine.js

I'm trying to add Alpine to an existing project that uses [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) to create select boxes. I'm having issues triggering actions when a selection is made.

I was trying something like this

```
<select id="fruits" class="form-control selectpicker"
  data-style="btn btn-picker"
  title="Add a skill"
  data-width="100%"
  data-live-search="true"
  x-model="fruit"
  x-on:changed.bs.select.window="addFruit()"
  x-on:click="addFruit()"
>
  <option">Apple</option>
  <option">Orange</option>
  <option">Banana</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that these events are never fired as bootstrap-select dynamically creates new elements.

Plus, although it fires a "changed.bs.select" when an option is selected, I'm having trouble capturing it on Alpine.

**Another attempt:**

I also tried capturing the bootstrap-select event on the Alpine opject:

```
<script>
    const fruitPicker = () => {
        return {
            fruit: "",
            init() {
                $(".selectpicker").on("changed.bs.select", (event) => {
                    console.log(`Event: ${event.target.value}`)
                    this.addFruit();
                });
            },
            addFruit() {
                console.log(`Fruit: ${this.fruit}`);
            }

        };
    };
</script>
```

And the console result:

```
Event: Apple
Fruit:
```

If I select another option after selecting "Apple":

```
Event: Banana
Fruit: Apple
```

So x-model is picking the wrong reference? I don't understand...

Is there a good way to make these two libraries play nice together?

Comment: jQuery uses a custom event system, that's why you were unable to catch `changed.bs.select` event with Alpine.js. However, I tried your second approach, and it was working fine for me, Alpine.js showed the same selected item as the event in the console. Have you tried [$watch](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/watch) method on `fruit` variable?

Comment: $watch is not working for me... (`Uncaught ReferenceError: $watch is not defined`). Is this perhaps some incompatibility with jQuery?

I'm thinking that maybe the 2nd approach works, but I'm not getting the results because of a race condition.

Comment: Inside a component, you have to use [`this.$watch()`](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data#using-magic-properties).

Comment: Ah, thanks! Yeah, the $watch method does show the proper output!